# callto handler from chrome extension popup window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, handler

I am trying to develop a chrome extension that when you click in the icon a popup window appears just below the icon (just the easiest thing to do). The popup contains some text and a phone number. I want this phone number to be clickable and that when you click on it a Skype call is triggered.

In a normal html page you would do this with something like:

```
< a href="callto:number" >Call us at number!< /a >
```

but when I put this code in the popup.html page and load the extension this is not working.

I have opened the popup.html page in a browser tab and the link works but it doesn't from the extension's popup. I have tested other handlers like `mailto` and it works, but `callto` doesn't.

I have also tried:

```
< a href="skype:number?call">Call us!< /a >
```

and it does not work neither.

Does anybody know why and how should I solve this issue?

thank you very much in advance

These are the files I have created:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

And the popup.html:

```
< html >
  < head >
    < title >Getting Started Extension's Popup< /title >
    < style >
      body {
        min-width:357px;
        overflow-x:hidden;
      }

      img {
        margin:5px;
        border:2px solid black;
        vertical-align:middle;
        width:75px;
        height:75px;
      }
    < /style>

  < body>
    < a href="callto:echo123">Call us free!< /a >
    < a href="skype:echo123?call">Call us free 2!< /a >
    < a href="mailto:mymail@gmail.com" target="_newtab">email us!< /a >
    < a href="http://www.elpais.es" target="_newtab"> el pais< /a >
  < /body >
</html>
```

Comment: Share related code, will pick up from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`< a href="callto:echo123">Call us free!< /a >` or `< a href="skype:echo123?call">Call us free 2!< /a >` is invoking a local program which is disallowed in chrome extensions;

[image]

If you want to invoke a local program you have to go for [NPAPI Plug-in](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, however invoking outlook is allowed in the extension. If I click on the "email us" link in the popupt window it invokes outlook. Is this because some programs are allowed while others are not?

Comment: @user1862963: Yes, for us outlook is default email client, it is whitelisted. Hope it helps

Comment: thanks! and I guess there is no way to whitelist Skype, is it?